# WPF Resources aren't loaded after SplashScreen implementation

Tags: wpf, mvvm, resources

i wanted to implement a splashscreen in my wpf application, where i can show some status messages. I found a good tutorial on how to do it.

I'm using mvvm toolkit.
My App.xaml has the StartupUri set to "View/Shell.xaml". This all works fine. Now I want to start the Splashscreen before the StartupUri is "called".

In the App.xaml.cs I implemented the main method like this:

```
[STAThread()]
    static void Main()
    {
        Splasher.Splash = new IPA.Merlin.View.ViewSplashScreen();
        Splasher.ShowSplash();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            MessageListener.Instance.ReceiveMessage(string.Format("Load module {0}", i));
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        new App();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        StartupUri = new System.Uri("View/Shell.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

        Run();
    }
```

For this to run i had to change the startupobject in project prefs to this main method.

So now my Splashscreen gets called and shows the test messages and after this App() is called. 
I get the following error: Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception with inner error : "Resource with the name {Locator} cannot be found

If I change the StartupUri to another Window, this windows resources also aren't found.
This occours only if i change the startupobject and then call app.run myself. Without the Splashscreen all Resources are found without problems.

Can anyone help me with this because it's making me crazy

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating `Main()` method, you can `override OnStartup` method which gets called `before main window gets initialized (App.xaml.cs)`-

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnStartup(e);

   Splasher.Splash = new IPA.Merlin.View.ViewSplashScreen();
   Splasher.ShowSplash();

   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
   {
      MessageListener.Instance.ReceiveMessage(string.Format("Load module {0}", i));
      Thread.Sleep(1);
   }

   Splasher.CloseSplash();
}
```

Comment: i tried this, but the OnStartup Event doesn't seem to fire. I checked this with a breakpoint. I also tried setting a new Startup function but VS is telling me that there is no definition for "Application_Startup". Any Ideas?

Comment: You need to put this method in `App` class and make sure you remove the static `Main` method since you can have only single entry point for your application.